# Getting capabilities from tomcat's Geoserver fails

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers-2, tomcat

I want to take capabilities from tomcat's geoserver, using this code:

```
wms = new OpenLayers.Format.WMSCapabilities();
OpenLayers.Request.GET({
    url:"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/filedata?request=GetCapabilities",
    success: function(e){
        var response = wms.read(e.responseText);
var capability = response.capability;
for (var i=0, len=capability.layers.length; i<len; i+=1) {
    var layerObj = capability.layers[i];
    if (layerObj.name === 'filedata') {
        map.zoomToExtent(OpenLayers.Bounds.fromArray(layerObj.llbbox));
        break;
    }
}
    }
});
```

But firebug says that "capability is not defined" in this string:

```
for (var i=0, len=capability.layers.length; i<len; i+=1) {
```

If I write the url from capability request in a browser, I get the error:

```
XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Adress: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/filedata?request=GetCapabilities
Line number 5091, column 21:          <Abstract><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF- 8"?>
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.3.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://localhost:8080/
geoserver/schemas/wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd">   <ServiceException>
--------------------^
```

But if I look in firebug, I can see that application got the capabilities.

In standalone Geoserver all works fine.

Comment: can you try to get your http://localhost:8080/geoserver. is it ok? or is there any error?

Comment: yes, i can see Geoserver on this url, its ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Service parameter is mandatory for making requests to WMS services. Your URL should looks like:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/filedata?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS
```

Comment: it not work too.

Comment: I find the error. If someone interest. Problem was in one of tomcat's geoserver standart layer.
In capabilities was error text.

    `javax.xml.transform.TransformerExeption: Translator error`
    `Translator error`
    `Error occurred trying to write out metadata for layer: Pk50095`
    `Unable to acquire a reader for this coverage with format: WorldImage`

Have no idea why it happening. But when im delete this layer all start work fine.

Tnx for your answers.

Comment: It's a known issue: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-4544